# Очистка git в jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins

Добрый день, коллеги.
Ситуация следующая: на удаленном серве стоит дженкинс, исходный код тянется из git-репозитория. При этом понятно, что клиент гита стоит на сервере с дженкинсом (как он в противном случае выполняет команды?). 
Случилась неприятная история с одной из веток и её надо удалить из серверного клиента гита. 
Вопрос такой: возможно ли через дженкинс добраться до этого гита?

Comment: Непосредственно гит-репозиторий находится в workspace той джобы, с которой у вас проблемы, поэтому можно хоть руками туда залезть и вычистить. Точный путь не подскажу, но он либо в /var/lib/jenkins/jobs, либо в /var/lib/jenkins/ws

Comment: @etki я немного неправильно выразился: до сервера нет доступа. Есть только до Дженкинса. Там пользователь создан, но сборка валится, потому что Дженкинс не может спулиться с репозитория, якобы там не головная ревизия.

Comment: Попробуйте установить очистку воркспейса перед чекаутом в расширенных настройках гита

Answer (score 0):

> Случилась неприятная история с одной из веток и её надо удалить из серверного клиента гита

Если вы туда отправили какие-то секретные данные, например криптографические ключи — считайте их скомпрометированными и попросту заменяйте на новые. Подчищая следы, вы не сделаете данные снова надёжными.

Как удалить все данные

1. Сначала нужно удалить эту ветку в репозитории, из которого Jenkins получает код.

   ```
   git push origin :bad_branch
   ```
2. Потом на Jenkins добавить в конфигурацию задачи этап со следующим shell-скриптом и выполнить его один раз:

   ```
   # чтобы не упасть на следующей команде, если там нет ветки
   set +e
   # удаляем локальную ветку, если есть
   git branch -D bad_branch

   # удаляем все tracking ветки, которых уже нет в удаленном репозитории
   # среди них есть и наша
   # вообще, я на 99% уверен, что Jenkins Git Plugin и так это делает
   git fetch --prune

   # проверяем результат (потом читаем логи)
   git branch -r
   ```

Если вам необходимо, чтобы ветку нельзя было даже восстановить после удаления, то придётся полностью удалить все ссылки на коммиты. Это произойдёт и само через некоторое время, но давайте предположим, что вам это зачем-то нужно.

> Осторожно: вы потеряете возможность восстановить любой «потерянный», т.е. не принадлежащий никакой существующей ветке коммит.

Это нужно выполнить на каждой машине, где вы хотите предать ветку полному забвению:

```
# чистим reflog и запускаем сборщик мусора
git reflog expire --expire=now --all \
  && git gc --prune=now \
  && git gc --aggressive --prune=now
```

Теперь коммитов и прочих объектов из нежелательной ветки нет не только в истории, но и вообще нигде в репозитории. Наверное, что-то всё же можно будет восстановить, имея физический доступ к диску и соответствующие навыки и инструменты.